# GNU Mailman Admin Interface Login

Tags: linux, apache, debian, mailing-list, mailman

Every time I try to get access to the webinterface via http://domain.com/admin/liste a Login Console prompts up, it requires a Username and a Password. What is that Username (and PW)?

Comment: Check if this helps you 
https://forums.cpanel.net/f5/mailman-lost-admin-password-4606.html

Comment: Hallo ich bin der Dieter und ich habe ein Problem.

Where did I exactly configure a Username?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you will see a username field. It should only ask you for a list password. The list password can be changed in Linux terminal using change_pw command, and site-wide password can be set using mmsitepass command.

List of mailman terminal commands:
http://www.gnu.org/software/mailman/site.html

Maybe you can tell us what system you are using.